# Change the direction of a Pen's arrow end cap

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to draw a line and show the arrow cap at the 'tail' of the line, like this:

[image]

Here is what I tried. The arrow cap is placed at the line's end, but its direction is not correct. It's coming downwards while I want it upwards like in the above image.

```
AdjustableArrowCap bigArrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5);
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
p.CustomEndCap = bigArrow;
g.DrawLine(p, X, Y, X, 50);
```

Comment: don't you mean drawing your arrow upward like this ? `g.DrawLine(p, X, 50, X, Y);`

Comment: Did you have  a look at the example on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.customlinecap(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TaW Yes its winforms. Its working but the direction of the arrow is still coming downwards.

Comment: @Franck nope, it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround, using a one-pixel extra line, but I think will do the job:

```
var img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(200, 200); 
using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(img)) {
   using (var p1 = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 2),
              p2 = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 2)) {
       using (var bigArrow = new AdjustableArrowCap(5, 5)) {
           p2.CustomEndCap = bigArrow;
           g.DrawLine(p1, 25, 50, 25, 100);
           g.DrawLine(p2, 25, 100, 25, 99);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

[image]

Comment: Please ensure that *all* objects implementing `IDisposable` are wrapped in a `using` statement—that includes `Pen` objects. I've fixed your code here, but this is something to keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 0):

This one uses `CustomLineCap`, it's not perfect but hopefully will give you a good direction

```
Graphics g= e.Graphics;
using (var path = new GraphicsPath()) {
    path.AddLine(new Point(-4, 4), new Point(4, 4));
    path.AddLine(new Point(4, 4), new Point(0, -1));
    path.AddLine(new Point(0, -1), new Point(-4, 4));
    using (var cap = new CustomLineCap(path, null))
    using (var customCapPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2) {CustomEndCap = cap}) { g.DrawLine(customCapPen, 10, 10, 10, 50); }
}
```